# Blender does not automatically create manifold when a space is enclosed by faces

Tags: mesh

Why doesn't blender automatically 'solidify' the space enclosed by faces? This makes no sense to me at all. If i use 3D printing add-on 'make manifold', blender goes crazy and start deleting vertices. At this moment, i have no hair left to pull. How do i force blender to make manifold any space enclosed by faces?

Comment: I don't know about the addon "Make Manifold", but why should Blender automatically solidify closed objects? After all it's a 3D modeling software not a special 3D printing software. Let's say I'll take a sphere and it's solidified automatically, this is useless geometry consuming resources if you just render the outiside surface. Or if you give it a glass shader to create a crystal ball, than the solidify has to be removed or else it's not a solid glass ball but only a sphere with thin glass walls....

Comment: Just to clarify, the mentioned add-on is called *3D-Print Toolbox* and one of its functions is *Make Manifold*. It usually does a very good job closing mesh holes.

Comment: Please provide screenshots of your interface and maybe your file https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manifold geometry just means it’s watertight. Your printer should automatically translate from a sort of paper model to something solid. It does this by working with the face normals. If the add-on thinks the geometry is not manifold, there might be a hole in it somewhere, or maybe some of the face normals are oriented backwards. Try selecting everything, then using “Merge by distance” to merge verses that are in the same mathematical position but are not connected. After that, with success or failure, try re-calculating all the normals to the outside.